# How do I run tests on my dnx50 project against dnx451?

Tags: c#, .net, dnx

For one of my projects, I need to downgrade entity framework from 7 to 6, and in order to do that, I need to use dnx451, instead of dnx50 (I think that's how that works anyway, I think 451 is the .net one below 50? idk).

Anywho, for that project, I have this dependency that I extracted to its own project, called csharp_extensions, and that dependency is what I want to have work with both dnx50 and dnx451.

Here is my project.json from my local csharp_extensions:

```
{
    "version": "1.1.0",
    "configurations": {
        "Debug": {
            "compilationOptions": {
                "define": [ "DEBUG", "TRACE" ]
            }
        },
        "Release": {
            "compilationOptions": {
                "define": [ "RELEASE", "TRACE" ],
                "optimize": true
            }
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "System.Reflection": "4.1.0-beta-*",
        "xunit": "2.1.0-*",
        "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-*"
    },
    "commands": {
        "run": "csharp_extensions",
        "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dnx541": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
                "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
                "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
                "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
                "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
            }
        },
        "dnxcore50": {
            "_": "this is the recommended windows runtime",
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-*",
                "System.Reflection.TypeExtensions": "4.1.0-beta-*",
                "System.Runtime.Extensions": "(4.0,]",
                "System.Dynamic.Runtime": "(4.0.0,]",
                "Microsoft.CSharp": "(4.0.0,]",
                "System.IO": "(4.0,]"
            }
        }

    },
}
```

and here is the project.json that works (for dnx50 only though) https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/csharp-extensions/blob/master/project.json
it's the same as what is pasted above, but no entry for dnx541.

With the above (pasted) project.json, when I try to build, it says everything succeeded, but when tests run, I get the following error:

```
------ Discover test started ------
------ Test started: Project: csharp-extensions ------
Starting  Microsoft.Dnx.TestHost [C:\Users\me\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\dnx.exe --appbase "C:\Users\me\Development\csharp-extensions" Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost --port 32182 Microsoft.Dnx.TestHost --port 36832 --parentProcessId 21136]

System.InvalidOperationException: The current runtime target framework is not compatible with 'csharp-extensions'.
Current runtime target framework: 'DNX,Version=v4.5.1 (dnx451)'
 Version:      1.0.0-rc1-16231
 Type:         Clr
 Architecture: x86
 OS Name:      Windows
 OS Version:   6.3
 Runtime Id:   win81-x86

Please make sure the runtime matches a framework specified in project.json
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.DefaultHost.GetEntryPoint(String applicationName)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain(DefaultHost host, String applicationName, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync(List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, String appBase, FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, BootstrapperContext bootstrapperContext)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.Execute(String[] args, BootstrapperContext bootstrapperContext)
Unable to start Microsoft.Dnx.TestHost
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:01.0852529) ==========
```

I'm pretty new to dnvm, and the commands don't make a whole lot of sense to me as far as being easy to remember (I'm used to rvm, from the ruby world, though)

Comment: If I use that project from GitHub and change the `project.json` to the one above, will that be what you are trying to do?

Comment: yup, I'm just trying to get the project to be compatible with dnx451, so I can use EF6 in my other project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx541": {
        …
```

You accidentally misspelt the framework version there. It should be **451** (as you correctly mentioned multiple times in your question), not 541. So since you’re running this with the `dnx451` framework (as specified in the error message), DNX will look for that framework in the configuration but cannot find it.

Comment: well, that's embarrassing.

Comment: If it makes it any better, I had to clone the project, try to run the tests three times, and copy parts of another `project.json` before I noticed it… :S